# Create Live Wallpaper in Android with multiple effects

Tags: android, live, effects, wallpaper

I am working with live wallpaper and i stuck with some problem,i need to create wallpaper with multiple effects like water rippling,sparkling effect,moving screens,i have a doubt that is it possible to create wallpaper with multiple effects.if it is possible how could i start with it.

I have checked this [RajawaliTemplate](https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliWallpaperTemplate) but it does not clear my doubts.

so could somebody help me out.@Thanks

Comment: try this ..https://www.google.co.in/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=live+wallpaper+in+android+example&oq=live+wallpaper+in+androi&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l3j0i22i30l7.1090.42245.1.44037.24.17.0.7.7.0.233.2577.0j15j2.17.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.hp.wuTq6-cVoZs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk&fp=ec94f01a283cf05e&biw=1315&bih=670

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here. Live wallpaper is not different from any android 3d game based on OpenGL ES. Where you can create as many effects as you want, switch between them, combine them, etc.

I created wallpaper with multiple effects called Alive Numbers 2 (More information - http://vitiy.info/alive-numbers-2-my-new-live-wallpaper-with-embedded-widgets/) where you can switch background animation, and this background animation contains composition of 2 effects - blur and particle system.

Comment: Victor thanks can you please help me to start with this OpenGL ES

Comment: As first start i would recommend to write not wallpaper but explore examples / simple lessons for Open GL ES. I would start from Open Gl ES 2.0 as it differs from first version quite a bit. http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html